# Crear una función que devuelva si las frases son iguales. Deberá recibir como parámetros las dos frases. Devolverá un booleano

Tags: c++

Tengo que:

> Crear una función que devuelva si las frases son iguales. Deberá recibir como parámetros las dos frases. Devolverá un booleano.

Este es el código que llevo:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char frase[50];
    char frase2[50];
}

void simi() {
    cout << "Primer dato" << endl;
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(frase, 50)

    cout << "segundo dato" << endl;
    cin.ignore(0);
    cin.getline(frase2, 50);

    if (strcmp(frase, frase2) == 0) {
        resp = true;
    } else {
        resp = false;
    }

    cout << resp << endl
}
```

No entiendo en que parte me equivoque, tal vez alguno pueda ayudarme.

Comment: Coloca tu código como texto. Nadie se va a dar el trabajo de reescribirlo para comprobar si funciona o no.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: Crear una función que devuelva si las frases son iguales. Deberá recibir como parámetros las dos frases. Devolverá un booleano.

ya agregue el codigo a la publicacion y muchas gracias por su ayuda <3

Comment: @Max Entiendo... ¿Cuál es el problema?

Comment: Como recomendación: No uses strings de C, usa el objeto `std::string`, que tiene el método `compare()`. De esa manera no tienes que usar funciones de C, como `strcmp()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bienvenido Max,

Mira tu código si lo has copiado y pegado de tu avance tiene muchos errores los enumero, para que tengas un feedback.

1. Si declaras tus char dentro de main, nunca serán leídos por tu función simi, por lo cual tienes que declararlos sobre main y si vas a comparar usar la libreria string.
2. Si vas a usar tu función simi, tienes que declararla también sobre main, y luego hacer un llamado dentro de tu funcion main principal.
3. Los cin ignore te estan jugando en contra para hacer la comparación y siempre te dara false.
4. Esta es un consejo, puedes usar boolalpha en el cout para que puedas mostrar el valor como true o false, y no 1 y 0.

> Entonces tenemos lo siguiente.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

char frase[50];
char frase2[50];
void simi ();

int main ()
{
  simi ();
}

void simi ()
{
  bool resp = true;
  string frasecita = "";
  cout << "Primer dato" << endl;
  cin.getline (frase, 50);

  cout << "segundo dato" << endl;
  cin.getline (frase2, 50);

  if (strcmp (frase, frase2) == 0)
    {
      resp = true;
    }
  else
    {
      resp = false;
    }
  cout << boolalpha << resp << endl;
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias, esque aun voy poco a poco con estos temas, disculpa mi pregunta al final pusiste boolalpha, que significa ?

Comment: Que va!, no tienes porque disculparte aqui entre todos nos apoyamos, mira lo que pasa es que si tu retornas resp, te dara 1 si es true y 0 si es false, con ese comodin podemos hacer que retorne true y false como palabra, quiere decir que en vez de mostrarte 1 y 0, te muestra true y false, retiralo y compruebalo.